# Visual Studio Code darkens code after closing brackets

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to figure out a weird formatting feature in Virtual Studio Code that drives me nuts.

If i open brackets in Visual Studio Code, the code "darkens" to show me where the bracket start and end.
While this usually works perfectly, there is some weird behavior using the code below

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
```

After closing the brackets in the first row, the entire code afterwards gets dark. After a while this really puts a strain on the eyes.

Is there any way to fix this ? What kind of setting is responsible for this formatting "feature"

Thanks in Advance !

Update (provided Screenshots of installed Extensions and Code Formatting)

[List of Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrQTy.png)
[Screenshot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT7jG.png)

I am using the Standard Dark+ Theme

My  settings.json can be found here - [settings.json](https://gist.github.com/Roemie/cada71b7f8a3b778471cc61881694da8)

Comment: After trying it, nothing has changed for me. Can you provide more information, like how your interface has changed, how do we know how `darkens` your interface is from your description alone? Also provide the theme you are using and your `settings.json`.

Comment: Provide a screenshot, a list of your installed extensions and their versions, and the name/extension-id of your theme.

Comment: Thanks for your effort guys, I have included screenshots for both - my extensions and the "dark" setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The darkening of the text indicates unreachable code, but I don't see why,
this is can be a bug with the Pylance (see:[bug](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/248)), you could disable the darkening feature, from settings UI with `Editor: Show Unused` or only for python from settings.json:

```
"[python]": {
        "editor.showUnused": false,
},
```

but it's not recommended, that can be a very helpful indicator.
You should update the Pylance extension and vscode if possible.

Comment: Thanks. I tried re-installing Pylance, however this did not result in the desired outcome. Hence I disabled the feature for now, let's see if there will be an update for this to fix the error. Thanks for your time and your valuable input